# auto-generated dynamic_reconfigure headers fail to compile depending on field names

Tags: ros-fuerte, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Fuerte, if a .cfg file used with dynamic_reconfigure contains a field named "i":

```
...
gen.add( "i", double_t, SensorLevels.RECONFIGURE_RUNNING, "i gain", 1, 0, 200 )
...
```

the header will fail to compile with:

```
no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘i = boost::any_cast [with ValueType = double]((* & val))’
```

The offending auto-generated code is:

```
class DEFAULT
{
  public:
    DEFAULT()
    {
      state = true;
      name = "Default";
    }

    void setParams(PIDConfig &config, const std::vector params)
    {
      for (std::vector::const_iterator i = params.begin(); i != params.end(); i++)
      {
        boost::any val;
        (*i)->getValue(config, val);

        if("p"==(*i)->name){p = boost::any_cast(val);}
        if("i"==(*i)->name){i = boost::any_cast(val);}
      }
    }

    double p;
double i;

    bool state;
    std::string name;

    
}groups;
```

Here, it's clear that setParams is using an iterator called "i", yet a member variable "i" of type "double" also exists within the same class.

While the obvious solution is to change the config field name from "i" to something like "i_gain" in this particular case, this issue breaks diamondback-compatible code and limits the names which may be used for dynamic_reconfigure fields.

To clarify, I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit/gcc 4.6.3 on a VM with a clean ROS install and the latest updates installed via dist-upgrade.

---

**Additional Issues**

It appears there are at least two more cases in which dynamic reconfigure param names can cause compilation issues.

When the class "DEFAULT" is added by the cfg generator:

```
class DEFAULT
{
  public:
    DEFAULT()
    {
      state = true;
      name = "Default";
    }

    ...

    // variables from user-specified fields

    ...

    // internal variables
    bool state;
    std::string name;
    
}groups;
```

the variables "state" and "name" appear to always be created, and will therefore conflict with any user-created variables with the same name.

To avoid these issues, it's probably a good idea to manually append "_param" or something similar to the name of all dynamic_reconfigure fields in .cfg files; however, as with the previous part of this issue, it would be great if this stuff would just work out-of-the-box.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46724/auto-generated-dynamic_reconfigure-headers-fail-to-compile-depending-on-field-names/) by [ekaszubski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3455/ekaszubski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2012-10-24

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-11-06**:
Wow, also it looks like there's no issue tracker for dynamic_reconfigure.

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-11-06**:
I just e-mailed Ze'ev about it, I'll post here when he gets back to me.

**Comment by [ekaszubski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3455/ekaszubski/) on 2012-11-07**:
Thank you, sir :)

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2012-11-09**:
Btw it is a little surprising that `Names` http://goo.gl/fqZut doesn't ban a single character parameter isn't it?

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-11-11**:
Well single character parameters shouldn't be a problem. Meanwhile, still nothing from Ze'ev.

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2013-07-08**:
i just ran into this same issue, documenting it on ros.org...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This issue is resolved in https://github.com/ros/dynamic_reconfigure/pull/26 and released in dynamic_reconfigure v1.5.37. The fix will be available in the Hydro and Indigo Debian packages in the next few days.

---

Originally posted by [esteve](https://answers.ros.org/users/4526/esteve/) with karma: 89 on 2014-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [esteve](https://answers.ros.org/users/4526/esteve/) on 2014-06-20**:
The fix will be available soon in Groovy as well https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/4798